# Laravel doesn't return relation id into child table (One To One Relationship)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, one-to-one

Im about to make Create Model Eloquent by having two table (one to one relationship) Task a parent to E-katalog as a child. But it doesn't work for my relation id(task_id) in my Ekatalog table

this is my Tables looks like

> **Task**

```
   id
   title
```

> **E-Katalog**

```
   id
   type
   task_id
```

My migrations :

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
}

Schema::create('ekatalogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('task_id')->nullable(),
            $table->string('type');
            ->nullable();
}
```

Relation in Model in my Task:

```
public function ekatalog(){
        return $this->hasOne(Ekatalog::class);
    }
```

Controller :

```
  //validation
  $taskData = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|max:255']);
  $ekatalogData =  $request->validate([
            'type' => 'max:255']);
  //create 
  $task->create($taskData);
  $task->ekatalog()->create($ekatalogData);
```

the code is working, but task_id in my Ekatalog is null. i thought it automatically make or generate value id by itself from parent's id(Task). How can i make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$task->create($taskData) will create a new object instance. Try this:

```
 //validation
  $taskData = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|max:255']);
  $ekatalogData =  $request->validate([
            'type' => 'max:255']);
  //create 
  $task = Task::create($taskData);
  $task->ekatalog()->create($ekatalogData);
```